# GIT não upa files novos ou alterados local remoto

Tags: git

Boa tarde a todos

Montei um servidor git para centralizar projetos e upar as alterações para servidores remotos, porem não consigo fazer o push enviar novos arquivos ou alterações nos existes no servidor cliente, fiz as configurações da seguinte maneira.

o Servidor cliente1 ja existe arquivos então acessei o diretório ja existente com arquivos e fiz `git init --shared` ele gerou os arquivos de config do git no `.git`

No servidor que será o centralizador do GIT

criei um diretório chamado /projeto a chave RSA ja esta configurada e acessível o user git tem permissão para criar ou alterar no diretório do cliente1

fiz o `git clone git@cliente1.com:/projeto/` e o projeto foi clonado para o servidor centralizador

```
Cloning into 'projeto'...
remote: Counting objects: 825, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (815/815), done.
remote: Total 825 (delta 73), reused 0 (delta 0)
Receiving objects: 100% (825/825), 234.39 MiB | 17.13 MiB/s, done.
Resolving deltas: 100% (73/73), done.
```

fiz um `git add --all`

criei um arquivo teste `touch teste`

```
git status

On branch master
Untracked files:
use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
    teste
```

depois um `git add -A` depois `git status`

```
On branch master
Changes to be committed:
 (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
  new file:   teste
```

Depois `git pull`:

```
Already up-to-date.
```

Depois `git commit teste`

Quando vou mandar o arquivo para o cliente1, `git push origin` retorna a mensagem

```
Everything up-to-date
```

mas o arquivo não é upado para o cliente1. Já fiz diversos testes e nada.

Se alguém puder me ajudar agradeço!

Comment: Você recebe alguma resposta do git depois que faz `git commit teste`? O que aparece se der um outro `git status` agora?

Comment: apareceu o seguinte
[master 6cdd3c9] arquivo teste
 1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 teste

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pessoal consegui resolver.

não entendi o motivo de acontecer isso mas faltou um arquivo no hooks o arquivo

post-commit.sample com a var

GIT_WORK_TREE=/projetos/ git checkout -f

adicionei este parâmetro e funcionou como esperado

Answer (score 2):

Sempre que for um commit é necessário informar uma mensagem.

```
git commit teste -m "arquivo teste"
```

Comment: olha so fiz o commit dessa maneira
git commit teste -m "arquivo teste"
[master 6cdd3c9] arquivo teste
 1 file changed, 0 insertions(+), 0 deletions(-)
 create mode 100644 teste

git status
# On branch master
# Your branch is ahead of 'origin/master' by 1 commit.
#   (use "git push" to publish your local commits)
#
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#
#       new teste